# What are the advantages of using GTK3 and GTK+3 over GTK-2?

Tags: gui, gtk, programming, gtk3, gtk-2

I'm creating a utility program for Ubuntu in Python using GTK-2 and have been told by several people to use GTK3.

Why would I want to do so, and would are the advantages of using it instead of GTK-2?